# How to find a file in GWT project using Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I've just created a GWT project and now I'm trying to search a file of the project, but Edit/Find in Eclipse is always unable..

Javi

Comment: but, I not even can write the name of file..You know I can't open the "Find" dialog...why do you say that it isn't there??

Comment: ok, I misunderstood you. Your question was not clear. I've responded with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the name of the file, you can use the **Open Resource** dialog (Navigate > Open Resource, or CTRL + Shift + R).

If you do not know the name of the file but know (at least some of) the contents, you can use the **File Search** dialog (Search > File, or CTRL + H then select the "File Search" tab).

Answer (score 1):

Edit-->Find does not search for files, it searches for text. Click on the button in your toolbar that looks like a little Flashlight, then select "File Search".